# Capture full stdout in python

Tags: python, redirect, stdout

This is a bit of a follow-up to the question: [Disable warnings originating from scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681946/disable-warnings-originating-from-scipy). The answer succeeds in redirecting any output intended for `stdout` to `/dev/null`. The new goal is to capture `stdout` as it's being printed so that I can examine it for the presence of certain strings. Here's a partial solution that raises a `MyError` whenever a string containing "warning" is printed to `stdout` using something like `print` or `sys.stdout.write()`:

```
import sys
import contextlib

class Warning_Catcher():
    def write(self, string):
        if 'warning' in string:
            raise MyError

@contextlib.contextmanager
def capture_warning():
    oldout, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, Warning_Catcher()
    try:
        yield sys.stdout
    except MyError:
        # handle error
    finally:
        sys.stdout = oldout

with capture_warning() as out:
    print 'warning'
```

However, it does not redirect things at the file descriptor level as explained in this other post on redirection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python/22434262#22434262).

My question is then: can I capture **all** output to `stdout` in a manner similar to the above code, raising an error if a certain string is found? The key is that I don't want to be writing to an actual file (which is why the original plan was to write everything to `/dev/null`). It seemed like using the 'tempfile' module with a moderate buffer size might work as this would allow me to use `dup2()` to completely redirect things, but this approach hasn't been met with success.