# redirecting integration error to file, python

Tags: python, error-handling

I am using odeint from scipy.itegrate in python. Sometimes I get integrating errors like,

> lsoda--  at current t (=r1), mxstep (=i1) steps
>          taken on this call before reaching tout
>         in above message,  i1 =       500
>         in above message,  r1 =  0.4082154636630D-03

I would like to NOT print those errors on the screen. Is there any way to print them directly to some error file? I just don't want them to be printed on the screen as I am printing something else there in big loop, and automatically to the result file.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect stderr in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956142/how-to-redirect-stderr-in-python)

Comment: I found perfect solution here: [answered question][1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681946/disable-warnings-originating-from-scipy

Answer (score 0):

If these messages are printed on the `stderr`, you can capture it and redirect to a file. A minimal implementation is

```
import sys
sys.stderr = open('the_log_file_for_errors', 'w')
```

Another, more complex, way can be to encapsulate the code that can give the error in a `try...except` block, in the except block you can do log the error on a file with some more details (like input params and so on) to check after.